# Código funcionando apenas no localhost

Tags: php

Montei um código para usar em uma rádio que possuo, puxando a capa da música que está tocando no momento, porém, apenas funciona no localhost. Quando entro pelo site, apenas aparece a imagem padrão que coloquei (Caso o servidor não encontre a imagem do álbum).

Alguém poderia me ajudar a saber qual o motivo?

*Não aparece nenhum erro de PHP ou quaisquer outros. Apenas a imagem da capa do servidor não é carregada, e fica no lugar a padrão...*

```php
$ip = "radioculturanf.ddns.net";
$port = "8000";
$api = "d5b942eae610872b133ca1f73bcbd3fe"; // 70bf8c268d5ea9d7d78a4f47e3b8ef35 57ee3318536b23ee81d6b27e36997cde

$fp = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,1);
if (!$fp) { 
    $title = "Rádio fora do ar!   ";
} else { 
    fputs($fp, "GET /7.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $info = fgets($fp);
    }
    $info = str_replace('</body></html>', "", $info);
    $split = explode(',', $info);
    if (empty($split[6])) {
        $title = "Título não disponível   ";
    } else {
        $count = count($split);
        $i = "6";
        while($i<=$count) {
            if ($i > 6) {
                @$title .= ", " . $split[$i];
            } else {
                @$title .= $split[$i];
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
$title = "@".substr($title, 0, -2)."#";

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$artista1  = get_string_between($title, '@', '- ');
$faixa1 = get_string_between($title, ' -', '#');


$artista = str_replace(" ", "+", trim($artista1));
$artista_final = str_replace("&amp", "&", $artista);
$artista_final = str_replace(",", "", $artista_final);

$faixa = str_replace(" ", "+", trim($faixa1));
$faixa_final = str_replace("&amp", "&", $faixa);
$faixa_final = str_replace(",", "", $faixa_final);

$api_include =  file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key='.$api.'&artist='.$artista_final.'&track='.$faixa_final.'', TRUE); 

 function get_string_between_api($string_api, $start_api, $end_api){
    $string_api = ' ' . $string_api;
    $ini_api = strpos($string_api, $start_api);
    if ($ini_api == 0) return '';
    $ini_api += strlen($start_api);
    $len_api = strpos($string_api, $end_api, $ini_api) - $ini_api;
    return substr($string_api, $ini_api, $len_api);
}

$imagem = get_string_between_api($api_include, '<image size="large">', '</image>');
if(empty($imagem)){
    $img_fin = "cd.jpg";
}else{
    $img_fin = $imagem; 
}

$img_total = str_replace("%20/%3E%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=", "", $img_fin);
$img_total2 = '<img src='.$img_total.' />';

echo '

<div class="media">
    <p>'.$img_total2.'</p>
    <p><span class="artista">'.$artista1.'</span></p>
    <p><span class="faixa">'.$faixa1.'</span></p>
</div>

';
```

Comment: Por favor forneça mais detalhes, que erro, mensagem está recebendo no servidor de produção?

Comment: Não aparece erro algum, apenas não carrega a imagem da capa do álbum. Usando esse código no localhost, tudo funciona. Já quando acesso via site, apenas carrega a imagem padrão, o que não está fazendo o mínimo de sentido para mim! hahahah

Comment: Queira [edit] sua postagem esclarecendo todos os pontos necessários para evitar fechamento, de preferência com os erros indicados no log  do PHP. Aproveitando, seria bom usar as tags corretas.

Comment: Desculpe mas parece que você está colocando a $img_total2 dentro do echo, e não está atribuindo nada à ela.

Comment: Bacco: Tentei editar mas ele estava cortando o código. Não entendi o motivo...

Comment: Rovann: Veja pelo link que disponibilizei acima. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente aqui no localhost. E não sei se você viu pelo código que estava no corpo da pergunta. Ele cortou algumas partes. No link que deixei ali está correto! rsrs

Comment: Parece ser um problema com o endereçamento, verifique os detalhes do `.htaccess` em uso. Contudo, faça o favor de editar a pergunta, fornecendo mais detalhes, e o código em uso se possível.

Comment: Aperte o F12 se for o Chrome e vá até a aba escrito "Console", veja que erros ocorreram.

Comment: A maneira mais fácil de adicionar código ao corpo do texto, é abrindo ele no editor de texto e adicionado um nível de tabulação nas linhas. Depois basta copiar e colar

Comment: Consegui colocar o código. Finalmente! rsrs Não apresenta nenhum erro, Guilherme.

Answer (score 1):

Erro resolvido. Era apenas mudar uma coisa ridiculamente simples no "php.ini".

A função de permitir abertura de url estava "off". Colocando "On", tudo está funcionando perfeitamente! rsrs

allow_url_fopen = On

Abraços